# How to apply a git patch on a non-checked out branch?

Tags: linux, git, tags

I am wondering if it is possible to apply a git patch on a non-checked out branch?

I would like to do this because I don't want this patch on my working branch, but on a dedicated branch that I don't use right now. This is a large branch, and checking it out will:

1. make my exuberant tags useless or broken. It takes long to rebuild them.
2. also, my kernel will force rebuild if I checkout this branch and roll-back to my working branch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's extremely indirect, but possible.  You can do it by applying it only to the index.

The easy way:

```
$ git read-tree <branch>
$ git apply --cached <patch>
$ git update-ref refs/heads/<branch> \
    -m "<optional reflog message>" \
    $(git commit-tree $(git write-tree) -m "<message>" -p <branch>)
```

If you want everything to be "cleaner" (i.e. have the reflog look normal for the commit), then here's a longer way, considerably more verbose:

```
$ git checkout -b temp             # Create a temp branch
$ git reset --mixed <branch>       # Reset the index to the branch you want
$ git apply --cached <patch>       # Apply the patch to the index
$ git commit                       # Create a commit object

  # Move the branch's reference to the new commit
$ git update-ref refs/heads/<branch> refs/heads/temp

  # Clean up
$ git checkout --force <original_branch>
$ git branch -d temp
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know `git read-tree`. I have to give your solution a try, that sounds risky and exciting :-). One question though: what do you call the "reflog"?

Comment: The reflog is a history of where branch and HEAD references have been in the repository. [Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/3004498).  In that example, the most recent "reflog message" would be "commit: test".  You can see this for your repository by running `git reflog [refs/heads/<branch>]`. (If you don't specify a branch, it assumes HEAD.)

Comment: (The easy way) Works beautifully. The only thing I noticed is that the changed files are staged after the update-ref. I am doing `git read-tree HEAD` to return to the original tree without fulling understanding what that does.

Answer (score 1):

Can you clone from your current repository to another directory, and check out the branch you want to work on there?  AFAIK, you can only apply a patch, or cherry pick commits, etc. to the files in your working directory.

For some of the projects I work on, I have multiple copies of a repository on my system, with different branches checked out on each.

Comment: that's probably what I will have to do, indeed.

Comment: @m-ric Idk if you've done it yet, but I figured out a way. :D  (I'm kindof proud of it.)

Comment: @vergenzt No I have not figured out a way. I think Peter van der Does is right, how would I deal with a patch failure? I rebuilt my kernel, as I do every mornings these last few days...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible mainly because of this reason:

How will you deal with a patch failure?

Comment: Hmmm, that makes sense. I agree it would be complicated.